# VBA - Count Duplicate values if > 2 tag the closest date to curdate

Tags: vba, excel

The script that i want is to count the duplicate values in a column, if value is greater than 2 tag it to the last column as "updated" based on the date column closest to the current date.

example:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
   1     | 1/2/2016 |
   2     | 1/3/2016 |
   3     | 1/4/2016 |
   1     | 1/5/2016 |
   1     | 1/6/2016 |
```

output:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
       1 | 1/2/2016 |
       2 | 1/3/2016 |
       3 | 1/4/2016 |
       1 | 1/5/2016 |
       1 | 1/6/2016 |  updated
```

In this example the value `1` in `Column A` have duplicate value `>2` so in `Column C` which is the last column it will be tag as `updated`...
there are three `1` in `Column A` but the closest date now is `1/6/2016` so it is the one that been tagged... if `<2` no action done..

Here's my code:

```
 Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C()

 Dim lastRow As Long
 Dim countRow As Long
 Dim iCntr As Long
 Dim CurDate As Date

 lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     For iCntr = 1 To lastRow

         If Cells(iCntr, 1) > 3 Then

         countRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)

     If iCntr <> countRow Then

     If CurDate <> iCntr Then

    Cells(iCntr, 3) = "Updated"

 End If
 End If
 End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

my code is not working but it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Are there any dates in the future? In other words, is the 'closest date to curdate' always going to be the latest date or is the differential between Today and each of the dates going to have to be calculated in order to determine a minimum differential?

Comment: yes, the file that i  would be using is a weekly report so i want to know  what value is the most updated date in those duplicate data.

Comment: MATCH function returns the position of the searched vale in the array. COUNTIF counts the occurrences of the searched value in the array. Besides that, your code doesn't do what you explained. For instance it starts checking the value in the first column is >3 which is not what you've written as your specs

Comment: @user3598756 2  i thought of using match to get the duplicate value and count if >3, so my approach is incorrect thanks for the advice and sorry im still new in vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your narrative contradicts your sample results in that there are not 'greater than 3' for **any** of the data. I'll just assume that is a typo and you meant 'greater than 2'.

A [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)'s [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) can readily detmine the frequency of the value in column A. While it is possible to evaluate an array formula to determine the maximum date from column B, in reality you only want to determine whether there are any dates later than the one being examined. If there aren't you have the latest date. A [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) can determine this faster than an array formula.

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, countRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<~~ you should know what worksheet you are on!!
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            countRow = Application.CountIf(.Columns(1), .Cells(i, 1))
            If countRow > 2 Then
                If Not CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(1), .Cells(i, 1), _
                                        .Columns(2), ">" & .Cells(i, 2))) Then _
                    .Cells(i, 3) = "updated"
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: max_date_one]

Comment: i do need to read a lot about match.function vs. countifs, thanks for the small discussion your code will help me a lot and im going to use this for future references, i appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: fine solution. just add a `.` before `Rows.Count` to be sure to refer to the proper worksheet. Moreover should not be trivial which workbook we're dealing with I'd add a `ThisWorkbook` or `ActiveWorkbook` (whichever applies) before `Worksheets(Sheet2")`. I'm coming with an alternative solution. could be interesting if 7A65726F could compare both on his/her workbook

Comment: @user3598756 - I use `.Rows.Count` inside a `.CurrentRegion` enough that I typically do not use the `.` when referring to the row count of the worksheet. Since it is only returning a number, it really doesn't matter which worksheet it refers to unless you have a mashup of .xls and .xlsx worksheets within the same application instance which I **very** rarely do and adjust my methods accordingly on those rare occasions. While I usually stress the importance of explicitly defining a parent worksheet, I leave the workbook definition to the OP.

Comment: @Jeeped - I see. From my side I actually still have that mashup so I take it as a habit to always add that dot. thank you

Comment: @Jeeped how can i range the month column here by 30days or 1month?

Comment: I guess the countifs will have to have another parameter to 'bracket' the month.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn_C2()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("duplicates")   '<~~ you should know what workbook and worksheet you are on!!
    With .Range("A1").Offset(, 2).Resize(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(C1,RC[-2])>2, IF(COUNTIFS(C1, RC[-2],C2," & """" & ">" & """" & "&" & "RC[-1])=0," & """" & "updated" & """" & "," & """" & """" & ")," & """" & """" & ")"
        .Value = .Value '<== if you want to get rid of formulas
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

it differs form Jeeped's one in that it doesn't iterate through cells. but it writes in every cells twice (first time to put formula in it and the second time to change it into a value to keep only needed markings) although in two statements only.

It'd be fine to know which is the fastest